# Programming iphone app using voice commands

Tags: iphone

Could anyone give me advice as to the most straightforward approach to integrate voice command in an app.
I have seen several posts that suggest using the sphinx speech recognition library, but they are dated 2 years.
Is the Siri API now available in the SDK?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [ispeech project](http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone)

Answer (score 0):

5 years past since the question was asked, and technologies didn't stay still all this time. Now, in iOS 10, Apple introduced two wonderful speech recognition frameworks:

[SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html), which allows to handle voice commands in your app. Unfortunately, it's limited to several intents: VoIP Calling, Messaging, Payments, Photos, Workouts, Ride Booking, Car Commands, Car Play and Restaurant Reservations.

[Speach Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech), that allows you to convert speech to text.